# DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

hello I created a table with some data that is needed but I have a problem every time an update is made the table "tarfecmod" should update the date but it is not doing it, stays with the first insert.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "CCPSEDCD"."RECFFTAPSE"
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"CCPSEDCD"."RECFFTAPSE_id_seq"'::regclass),
tarmoda character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
tarfecmod time without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
tariva real,
CONSTRAINT "RECFFTAPSE_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

Comment: A default value is only used when you don't specify a value during an INSERT. Once the row is created, the default value is pretty much meaningless

Comment: Yeah, if you want to change the time on update you will either need to supply the time in the `UPDATE` or create a  `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger/function that  does that. FYI, since the field is of type `timewithout time zone` you might as well save the implicit cast and tz conversion and use `LOCALTIME` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: what your insert looks like ?